# 1>0 in a field with order relation modern algebrn

Tags: abstract-algebra

Just a quick question.In a field, how to prove that 1>0, i don't know how to deal with it if the field has order relation,and if x>y then x+z>y+z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to use the other requirement on the order: that if $0\le x$ and $0\le y$, then $0\le xy$. Suppose that $1<0$. Then $0=1+(-1)<0+(-1)=-1$, i.e., $0<-1$. But then $0<(-1)^2=1$, a contradiction.